# Find human-readable files

Tags: files, find

I am trying to find an efficient way to do the [level 5 of the OverTheWire bandit challenge](https://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/bandit6.html).

Anyway, I have a bunch of files and there is only one that fulfills the following criteria:

- Human-readable
- 1033 bytes in size
- Non-executable

Right now, I am using the [`find`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command. I am able to find the files matching the two last criteria:

```
find . -size 1033c ! -executable
```

However, I don't know how to exclude non-human-readable files. Solutions I found for that challenge use the `-readable` test parameter, but I don't think this works. `-readable` only looks at the files' permissions, and not at its content, while the challenge description asks for an ASCII file or something like that.

Comment: How do you define human readable? Not binary?

Comment: file command is your friend :)

Comment: Maybe duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505218/finding-human-readable-files-on-unix

Comment: @zuazo there's no such thing as cross-site duplicates. That post might have the answer, but it isn't a "duplicate".

Comment: I believe that *human-readable* would be defined as ASCII text. The description doesn't give any details!

Comment: @J.Doe so UTF is out? I know the description doesn't give details, but this is your question, so you have to choose :)

Comment: Humans are one of the most intelligent known species on earth. They're also the only one known to versed with computers. They can read most files provided they can find out the type and get hold of the encryption keys for encrypted one.

Comment: Having gone through Bandit myself, after filtering by size and permission flags there are not awfully many files left to choose from. So for the sake of passing the level, just have a look at each of them.

Comment: I just did it and there's only one file returned by a simple `find inhere/  -size 1033c ! -executable`

Comment: There is no silver bullet that can do this. It's *** you *** who chooses the heuristics for what a >>human-readable file<< is and then go about putting those heuristics in a function/script/alias and implant that in `find`.

Comment: SPOILER ALERT!!

Comment: There is a command `strings` that extracts human readable strings from a binary file. Try `strings /bin/ls` for example. If you have human readable file, all content should be printed out with `strings`. There are some differences as empty new lines are not printed out with strings, so just running `diff` between the `cat file` and `strings file` will not necessarily work, but I think `strings` could be used with some additional checks.

Answer (score 32):

Yes, you can use `find` to look for non-executable files of the right size and then use `file` to check for ASCII. Something like:

```
find . -type f -size 1033c ! -executable -exec file {} + | grep ASCII
```

The question, however,  isn't as simple as it sounds. 'Human readable' is a horribly vague term. Presumably, you mean text. OK, but what kind of text? Latin character ASCII only? Full Unicode? For example, consider these three files:

```
$ cat file1
abcde
$ cat file2
αβγδε
$ cat file3
abcde
αβγδε
$ cat file4
#!/bin/sh
echo foo
```

These are all text and human readable. Now, let's see what `file` makes of them:

```
$ file *
file1: ASCII text
file2: UTF-8 Unicode text
file3: UTF-8 Unicode text
file4: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

So, the `find` command above will only find `file1` (for the sake of this example, let's imagine those files had 1033 characters). You could expand the `find` to look for the string `text`:

```
find . -type f -size 1033c ! -executable -exec file {} + | grep -w text
```

With the `-w`, `grep` will only print lines where `text` is found as a stand-alone word. That *should* be pretty close to what you want, but I can't guarantee that there is no other file type whose description might also include the string `text`.

Answer (score 8):

While `-exec` is mostly used to do something with the files that where found, it can also act as a test. Therefore, we can add it to your other criteria:

```
find . \
  -size 1033c \
  -not -executable \
  -exec sh -c 'file {} | grep "text$"' \;
```

Remember, `grep` returns non-zero when the pattern wasn't found, and `sh -c "COMMAND"` will return the result of the evaluation (as long as it's valid). So this will only print files where `file <filename>` spits something out that ends with `text`, e.g. "UTF-8 Unicode text` or "ASCII text", but not "Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with escape sequences".

In a single line, it even ends up shorter than going over `xargs`:

```
find . -size 1033c -not -executable -exec sh -c 'file {} | grep "text$"' \;
```

Keep in mind that you can replace `sh -c 'file {} | grep "text$"'` with any custom command. If you want to check for something very complex, it might be a better idea to provide a shell script and use that instead:

```
find . -size 1033c -not -executable -exec is_human_readable.sh {} \;
```

which, in the long run, is easier to maintain than your shell's history:

```
#!/bin/sh
file "$@" | grep "text$" > /dev/null
```

Comment: Nice! Note, however, that matching `text$` will exclude things recognized as shell scripts. Anything with a shebang is identified as a script, and those are perfectly human readable.

Comment: @terdon true, but scripts tend to be executable :D. That being said, a proper script should also recognize PDFs. But on the other hand, is a PDF containing an image human _readable_? Is a PNG of some text _readable_? Probably. I guess a complet test will be… challenging.

Answer (score 4):

There is only 1 file with `1033` bytes of size.

```
bandit5@bandit:~$ find -size 1033c
./inhere/maybehere07/.file2
bandit5@bandit:~$
```

Why `1033c` and not `1033`? Check the `man` page

> ```
>    -size n[cwbkMG]
>           File uses n units of space, rounding up.  The following suffixes can be used:
>
>           `b'    for 512-byte blocks (this is the default if no suffix is used)
>
>           `c'    for bytes
>
>           `w'    for two-byte words
>
>           `k'    for Kilobytes (units of 1024 bytes)
>
>           `M'    for Megabytes (units of 1048576 bytes)
>
>           `G'    for Gigabytes (units of 1073741824 bytes)
> ```

Verify it with `ls -l` and `file` command, and you get all the answer.

```
bandit5@bandit:~$ ls -l ./inhere/maybehere07/.file2
-rw-r----- 1 root bandit5 1033 May  7 20:15 ./inhere/maybehere07/.file2
bandit5@bandit:~$ 
bandit5@bandit:~$ file ./inhere/maybehere07/.file2
./inhere/maybehere07/.file2: ASCII text, with very long lines
bandit5@bandit:~$
```

1. human-readable (`ASCII text`)
2. 1033 bytes in size (Also in `ls -l` output)
3. not executable (`-rw-r-----`)

Answer (score 2):

You only need to use:

```
find inhere -size 1033c
```

It will give you the only file that contains the password.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -size 1033c ! -executable -exec file {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

Just run the following against the contents of the directory:

```
$ file -- *
-file00: data
-file01: data
-file02: data
-file03: data
-file04: data
-file05: data
-file06: data
-file07: ASCII text
-file08: data
-file09: data
$ cat -- \-file07
<output>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
find . -size 1033c ! -executable -exec file {} +
```

*Your challenge does not allows  `grep`. password file will be reported as "ASCII text, with very long lines"*

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -size 1033c ! -executable|xargs file|grep "ASCII text" |awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

Please try this combined commands. it works on my station.

Answer (score 0):

To filter out the human-readable file names, you can make use of the `[:print:]` (*printable*) **character class** name. You will find more about such classes in the manual for `grep`.

```
find . -type f -size 1033c -name "[[:print:]]*" ! -executable
```

---

On a second thought, the "human-readable" requirement might refer to the file's content, instead of its name. In other words, you would be searching for *text* files. That is a little more tricky. As @D_Bye suggested in a comment, you should then use the `file` command to determine the file content type. But it would not be a good idea to run `file` after a pipe, because it would complicate the task of displaying the file's name. Here's what I suggest:

```
find . -type f -size 1033c ! -executable -exec sh -c 'file -b $0 | grep -q text' {} \; -print
```

This is briefly how the `file`-part works:

- The **`-exec`** predicate executes `sh -c 'file -b $0 | grep -q text' FILENAME` for each `FILENAME` that satisfies all the previous conditions (type, size, non-executable).
- For each of those files, a shell (`sh`) runs this short **script**: `file -b $0 | grep -q text`, replacing `$0` with the filename.
- The **`file`** program determines the content type of each file and outputs this information. The `-b` option prevents printing the name of each tested file.
- **`grep`** filters the output coming from `file` program, searching for lines containing *"text"*. (See for yourself, how a typical output of the `file` command looks like.)
- But `grep` does not output the filtered text, because it has the **`-q`** (quiet) option given. What it does, is just change its *exit status* to either `0` (which represents "true" - the filtered text was found) or 1 (meaning "error" - the text *"text"* did not appear in the output from `file`).
- The true/false exit status coming from `grep` is passed further by `sh` to `find` and acts as the final result of the whole "`-exec sh -c 'file $0 | grep -q text' {} \;`" test.
- In case the above test returned *true*, the `-print` command is executed (i.e. the name of the tested file is printed).

Answer (score 0):

```
bandit4@bandit:~$ ls
inhere

bandit4@bandit:~$ file inhere/*


inhere/-file00: data
inhere/-file01: data
inhere/-file02: data
inhere/-file03: data
inhere/-file04: data
inhere/-file05: data
inhere/-file06: data
inhere/-file07: ASCII text
inhere/-file08: data
inhere/-file09: data

bandit4@bandit:~$ pwd 

/home/bandit4

bandit4@bandit:~$ cat /home/bandit4/inhere/-file07

koReBOKuIDDepwhWk7jZC0RTdopnAYKh
bandit4@bandit:~$
```

Comment: Simply use                  file inhere/*  and cat /home/bandit4/inhere/-file07

Answer (score 0):

```
find  -type f ! -executable -size 1033c
```

will get you the file from the exercise

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -size 1033c ! -executable | xargs file | grep text
```

Fan of one liners

Answer (score 0):

I think the longer way of finding the password for this bandit level mentioned by most above using find and grep is the most descriptive command.

`find . -type f -size 1033c ! -executable -exec file {} + | grep ASCII`

But, after using the 'file' command more I realized its quite easy to locate human-readable files (aka ASCII in this level) this way by checking an entire directories file types. The inhere directory holds files with name '-filexx' or quickly check the entire inhere directory with `file ./*`

Here was my approach.

```
bandit4@bandit:~/inhere$ file ./*
./-file00: data
./-file01: data
./-file02: data
./-file03: data
./-file04: data
./-file05: data
./-file06: data
./-file07: ASCII text
./-file08: data
./-file09: data

bandit4@bandit:~/inhere$ cat ./-file07
koReBOKuIDDepwhWk7jZC0RTdopnAYKh
```