# Significance of "{} +" in command "find . -type f -size 1033c ! -executable -exec file {} + | grep ASCII"

Tags: linux, files, find

What is the significance of `{} +` in this command?

```bsh
find . -type f -size 1033c ! -executable -exec file {} + |
grep ASCII
```

Can you explain to me what it does by breaking the command down? I am a noob.

Comment: Seems related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313462/117549

Answer (score 0):

`{} +` means the collection of files/directories found.

For example:

```
find . -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} + ;
```

this will find the empty directories and the run `rmdir DIRNAME1 DIRNAME2 ...`.

Comment: what "grep ASCII" does?

Comment: @user403513 it finds the lines that contains ASCII. Why don't you just google or run `grep --help` or `man grep` to know what grep's about?